# VB 2010 read INI inside of HTML text

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, html-parsing

I need to read a INI text inside of an HTML text, and get every part of the INI with Visual Basic 2010.

But it's inside a website, and it contains HTML tags before and after, and even inside, like this:

```
... more HTML
<div ... >
[inipart1]<br />
param1=1<br />
param2=text<br />
param3=Yes<br />
param4=link<br />
[inipart2]<br />
param1=1<br />
param2=text<br />
param3=Yes<br />
param4=link
</div>
... more HTML
```

I need to remove all HTML parts (all before inside and after) and read the INI part as any other INI file; I need to turn it into this:

```
[inipart1]
param1=1
param2=text
param3=Yes
param4=link
[inipart2]
param1=1
param2=text
param3=Yes
param4=link
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public string StripHtml(string text)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text, @"<(.|\n)*?>", "");
}
```

PS: You have to include the System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace

Answer (score 1):

If you can be certain that the INI values or parameters will not contain any greater-than or less-than signs, you can write a regular expression which filters out all HTML tags.